# Why is my singularity pull failing in my nextflow script?

Tags: docker, containers, bioinformatics, singularity-container, nextflow

I have looked hard for an answer, but haven't managed to find one, so I'm hoping someone here can help me understand this error and what is happening during the singularity pull command.

Here is the error:

```
Error executing process > 'QC_TRIM_READS (1)'

Caused by:
  Failed to pull singularity image
  command: singularity pull  --name quay.io-biocontainers-sickle-trim-1.33--2.img.pulling.1632264509884 docker://quay.io/biocontainers/sickle-trim:1.33--2 > /dev/null   
  status : 127
  message:
    WARNING: pull for Docker Hub is not guaranteed to produce the
    WARNING: same image on repeated pull. Use Singularity Registry
    WARNING: (shub://) to pull exactly equivalent images.
    /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
    ERROR: pulling container failed!
```

Here is the script (excuse the mess, I am just getting used to nextflow)

```
#!/usr/bin/env Nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.ref_genome = "./data/GmaxFiskeby_678_v1.0.fa"
params.ref_annotation = "./data/GmaxFiskeby_678_v1.1.gene_exons.gff3"

params.intermediate_dir = "$workDir/intermediate/"

workflow {

  ref_genome_ch = Channel.fromPath("$params.ref_genome")
  ref_annotation_ch = Channel.fromPath("$params.ref_annotation")

  input_fastq_ch = Channel.fromPath("./data/*.fastq")

  ref_genome_ch.view()

  QC_TRIM_READS(input_fastq_ch)
  STAR_INDEX_GENOME(ref_genome_ch, ref_annotation_ch)

}

process GZIP_VERSION {
  echo true

  script:
  """
  gzip --version
  """
}

process UNZIP {
  publishDir "intermediate/"

  input:
  path file

  output:
  path "${file.baseName}"

  script:
  """
  gzip -dfk ${file}
  """
}

process QC_TRIM_READS {
  publishDir "intermediate/"

  container 'quay.io/biocontainers/sickle-trim:1.33--2'

  input:
  path fastqFile

  output:
  path "${fastqFile.baseName}_trimmed.${fastqFile.getExtension()}"

  script:
  """
  sickle se \\
     -f $fastqFile \\
     -t sanger \\
     -o ${fastqFile.baseName}_trimmed.${fastqFile.getExtension()} \\
     -q 35 \\
     -l 45
  """

}

process STAR_INDEX_GENOME {
  publishDir "intermediate/indexedGenome/"

  /*if (worflow.containerEngine == 'singularity'){
    container "https://depot.galaxyproject.org/singularity/mulled-v2-1fa26d1ce03c295fe2fdcf85831a92fbcbd7e8c2:59cdd445419f14abac76b31dd0d71217994cbcc9-0"
  } else {*/
  container "quay.io/biocontainers/mulled-v2-1fa26d1ce03c295fe2fdcf85831a92fbcbd7e8c2:59cdd445419f14abac76b31dd0d71217994cbcc9-0" //'quay.io/biocontainers/star:2.6.1d--0'
  //}

  input:
  path genome
  path gtf

  output:
  path "star"      , emit: index

  script:
  """
  STAR \\
     --runMode genomeGenerate \\
     --genomeDir star/ \\
     --genomeFastaFiles ${genome}\\
     --sjdbGTFfile ${gtf} \\
     --sjdbGTFtagExonParentTranscript Parent \\
     --sjdbOverhang 100 \\
     --runThreadN 2
  """
}
```

Here is my configuration file:

```
//docker.enabled = false
singularity.enabled = true
singularity.autoMounts = true
```

I built my environment as a conda environment, here is the yml file:

```
name: nf-core
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_gnu
  - attrs=21.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py38h27cfd23_1003
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
  - c-ares=1.17.1=h27cfd23_0
  - ca-certificates=2021.7.5=h06a4308_1
  - cairo=1.14.12=h7636065_2
  - cattrs=1.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - certifi=2021.5.30=py38h06a4308_0
  - cffi=1.14.6=py38h400218f_0
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - click=8.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - colorama=0.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - commonmark=0.9.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - coreutils=8.32=h7b6447c_0
  - cryptography=3.4.7=py38hd23ed53_0
  - curl=7.78.0=h1ccaba5_0
  - expat=2.4.1=h2531618_2
  - fontconfig=2.12.6=h49f89f6_0
  - freetype=2.8=hab7d2ae_1
  - fribidi=1.0.10=h7b6447c_0
  - future=0.18.2=py38_1
  - gettext=0.21.0=hf68c758_0
  - git=2.32.0=pl5262hc120c5b_1
  - gitdb=4.0.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - gitpython=3.1.18=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - glib=2.69.1=h5202010_0
  - graphite2=1.3.14=h23475e2_0
  - graphviz=2.40.1=h25d223c_0
  - harfbuzz=1.7.6=h5f0a787_1
  - hdf5=1.10.6=hb1b8bf9_0
  - icu=58.2=he6710b0_3
  - idna=3.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - importlib-metadata=4.8.1=py38h06a4308_0
  - importlib_metadata=4.8.1=hd3eb1b0_0
  - itsdangerous=2.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jinja2=3.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jpeg=9d=h7f8727e_0
  - jsonschema=3.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - krb5=1.19.2=hac12032_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=h7274673_9
  - libcurl=7.78.0=h0b77cf5_0
  - libedit=3.1.20210714=h7f8727e_0
  - libev=4.33=h7b6447c_0
  - libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
  - libgcc-ng=9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - libgfortran-ng=7.5.0=ha8ba4b0_17
  - libgfortran4=7.5.0=ha8ba4b0_17
  - libgomp=9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - libiconv=1.15=h63c8f33_5
  - libnghttp2=1.41.0=hf8bcb03_2
  - libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - libssh2=1.9.0=h1ba5d50_1
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.3.0=hd4cf53a_17
  - libtiff=4.2.0=h85742a9_0
  - libtool=2.4.6=h7b6447c_1005
  - libwebp-base=1.2.0=h27cfd23_0
  - libxcb=1.14=h7b6447c_0
  - libxml2=2.9.12=h03d6c58_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.3=h295c915_1
  - markupsafe=2.0.1=py38h27cfd23_0
  - ncbi-ngs-sdk=2.10.4=hdf6179e_0
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_1
  - nextflow=21.04.0=h4a94de4_0
  - nf-core=2.1=pyh5e36f6f_0
  - openjdk=8.0.152=h7b6447c_3
  - openssl=1.1.1l=h7f8727e_0
  - ossuuid=1.6.2=hf484d3e_1000
  - packaging=21.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pango=1.42.0=h377f3fa_0
  - pcre=8.45=h295c915_0
  - pcre2=10.35=h14c3975_1
  - perl=5.26.2=h14c3975_0
  - perl-app-cpanminus=1.7044=pl526_1
  - perl-business-isbn=3.004=pl526_0
  - perl-business-isbn-data=20140910.003=pl526_0
  - perl-carp=1.38=pl526_3
  - perl-constant=1.33=pl526_1
  - perl-data-dumper=2.173=pl526_0
  - perl-encode=2.88=pl526_1
  - perl-exporter=5.72=pl526_1
  - perl-extutils-makemaker=7.36=pl526_1
  - perl-file-path=2.16=pl526_0
  - perl-file-temp=0.2304=pl526_2
  - perl-mime-base64=3.15=pl526_1
  - perl-parent=0.236=pl526_1
  - perl-uri=1.76=pl526_0
  - perl-xml-libxml=2.0132=pl526h7ec2d77_1
  - perl-xml-namespacesupport=1.12=pl526_0
  - perl-xml-sax=1.02=pl526_0
  - perl-xml-sax-base=1.09=pl526_0
  - perl-xsloader=0.24=pl526_0
  - pip=21.2.2=py38h06a4308_0
  - pixman=0.40.0=h7b6447c_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.17=pyhca03da5_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.17=hd3eb1b0_0
  - pycparser=2.20=py_2
  - pygments=2.10.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyopenssl=20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - pyparsing=2.4.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyrsistent=0.17.3=py38h7b6447c_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py38h06a4308_0
  - python=3.8.11=h12debd9_0_cpython
  - python_abi=3.8=2_cp38
  - pyyaml=5.4.1=py38h27cfd23_1
  - questionary=1.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - readline=8.1=h27cfd23_0
  - requests=2.26.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - requests-cache=0.7.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rich=10.10.0=py38h578d9bd_0
  - setuptools=58.0.4=py38h06a4308_0
  - singularity=2.4.2=0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - smmap=4.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sqlite=3.36.0=hc218d9a_0
  - sra-tools=2.11.0=pl5262h314213e_0
  - tabulate=0.8.9=py38h06a4308_0
  - tk=8.6.10=hbc83047_0
  - typing-extensions=3.10.0.2=hd3eb1b0_0
  - typing_extensions=3.10.0.2=pyh06a4308_0
  - url-normalize=1.4.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - urllib3=1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - wheel=0.37.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - zipp=3.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.4.9=haebb681_0
prefix: /home/mkozubov/miniconda3/envs/nf-core
```

Here is the log file:

```
Sep-21 16:00:49.076 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cli.Launcher - $> nextflow run rnaseq.nf
Sep-21 16:00:49.318 [main] INFO  nextflow.cli.CmdRun - N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.0
Sep-21 16:00:49.367 [main] INFO  nextflow.cli.CmdRun - Launching `rnaseq.nf` [reverent_jepsen] - revision: 0fc00d31fc
Sep-21 16:00:49.414 [main] DEBUG nextflow.config.ConfigBuilder - Found config local: /mnt/c/Users/mkozubov/Desktop/nextflow_tutorial/rnaseq/nextflow.config
Sep-21 16:00:49.418 [main] DEBUG nextflow.config.ConfigBuilder - Parsing config file: /mnt/c/Users/mkozubov/Desktop/nextflow_tutorial/rnaseq/nextflow.config
Sep-21 16:00:49.506 [main] DEBUG nextflow.config.ConfigBuilder - Applying config profile: `standard`
Sep-21 16:00:50.238 [main] DEBUG nextflow.plugin.PluginsFacade - Setting up plugin manager > mode=prod; plugins-dir=/home/mkozubov/.nextflow/plugins
Sep-21 16:00:50.240 [main] DEBUG nextflow.plugin.PluginsFacade - Plugins default=[]
Sep-21 16:00:50.242 [main] DEBUG nextflow.plugin.PluginsFacade - Plugins local root: .nextflow/plr/empty
Sep-21 16:00:50.258 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.DefaultPluginStatusProvider - Enabled plugins: []
Sep-21 16:00:50.262 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.DefaultPluginStatusProvider - Disabled plugins: []
Sep-21 16:00:50.266 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.DefaultPluginManager - PF4J version 3.4.1 in 'deployment' mode
Sep-21 16:00:50.289 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.AbstractPluginManager - No plugins
Sep-21 16:00:50.366 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session uuid: 22a13149-e9f8-47cc-8f09-98a6b000a83a
Sep-21 16:00:50.367 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Run name: reverent_jepsen
Sep-21 16:00:50.372 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Executor pool size: 5
Sep-21 16:00:50.418 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cli.CmdRun - 
  Version: 21.04.0 build 5552
  Created: 02-05-2021 16:22 UTC (09:22 PDT)
  System: Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
  Runtime: Groovy 3.0.7 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_152-release-1056-b12
  Encoding: UTF-8 (UTF-8)
  Process: 10590@DESKTOP-UJ90D1J [127.0.1.1]
  CPUs: 5 - Mem: 1.9 GB (311.8 MB) - Swap: 1 GB (783.4 MB)
Sep-21 16:00:50.539 [main] DEBUG nextflow.file.FileHelper - Can't check if specified path is NFS (1): /mnt/c/Users/mkozubov/Desktop/nextflow_tutorial/rnaseq/work
  v9fs

Sep-21 16:00:50.541 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Work-dir: /mnt/c/Users/mkozubov/Desktop/nextflow_tutorial/rnaseq/work [null]
Sep-21 16:00:50.545 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Script base path does not exist or is not a directory: /mnt/c/Users/mkozubov/Desktop/nextflow_tutorial/rnaseq/bin
Sep-21 16:00:50.585 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - Extension executors providers=[]
Sep-21 16:00:50.616 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Observer factory: DefaultObserverFactory
Sep-21 16:00:50.999 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session start invoked
Sep-21 16:00:51.461 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Launching execution
Sep-21 16:00:51.511 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Workflow process names [dsl2]: QC_TRIM_READS, UNZIP, STAR_INDEX_GENOME, GZIP_VERSION
Sep-21 16:00:51.643 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - << taskConfig executor: null
Sep-21 16:00:51.643 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - >> processorType: 'local'
Sep-21 16:00:51.651 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.Executor - [warm up] executor > local
Sep-21 16:00:51.656 [main] DEBUG n.processor.LocalPollingMonitor - Creating local task monitor for executor 'local' > cpus=5; memory=1.9 GB; capacity=5; pollInterval=100ms; dumpInterval=5m
Sep-21 16:00:51.868 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - << taskConfig executor: null
Sep-21 16:00:51.869 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - >> processorType: 'local'
Sep-21 16:00:51.904 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Ignite dataflow network (5)
Sep-21 16:00:51.963 [main] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Starting process > QC_TRIM_READS
Sep-21 16:00:51.965 [main] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Starting process > STAR_INDEX_GENOME
Sep-21 16:00:51.966 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Await termination 
Sep-21 16:00:51.968 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await
Sep-21 16:00:51.969 [PathVisitor-3] DEBUG nextflow.file.PathVisitor - files for syntax: glob; folder: ./data/; pattern: *.fastq; options: [:]
Sep-21 16:00:52.300 [Actor Thread 8] WARN  nextflow.container.SingularityCache - Singularity cache directory has not been defined -- Remote image will be stored in the path: /mnt/c/Users/mkozubov/Desktop/nextflow_tutorial/rnaseq/work/singularity -- Use env variable NXF_SINGULARITY_CACHEDIR to specify a different location
Sep-21 16:00:52.300 [Actor Thread 8] INFO  nextflow.container.SingularityCache - Pulling Singularity image docker://quay.io/biocontainers/sickle-trim:1.33--2 [cache /mnt/c/Users/mkozubov/Desktop/nextflow_tutorial/rnaseq/work/singularity/quay.io-biocontainers-sickle-trim-1.33--2.img]
Sep-21 16:00:52.300 [Actor Thread 7] INFO  nextflow.container.SingularityCache - Pulling Singularity image docker://quay.io/biocontainers/mulled-v2-1fa26d1ce03c295fe2fdcf85831a92fbcbd7e8c2:59cdd445419f14abac76b31dd0d71217994cbcc9-0 [cache /mnt/c/Users/mkozubov/Desktop/nextflow_tutorial/rnaseq/work/singularity/quay.io-biocontainers-mulled-v2-1fa26d1ce03c295fe2fdcf85831a92fbcbd7e8c2-59cdd445419f14abac76b31dd0d71217994cbcc9-0.img]
Sep-21 16:00:52.433 [Actor Thread 5] ERROR nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Error executing process > 'QC_TRIM_READS (1)'

Caused by:
  Failed to pull singularity image
  command: singularity pull  --name quay.io-biocontainers-sickle-trim-1.33--2.img.pulling.1632265252300 docker://quay.io/biocontainers/sickle-trim:1.33--2 > /dev/null
  status : 127
  message:
    WARNING: pull for Docker Hub is not guaranteed to produce the
    WARNING: same image on repeated pull. Use Singularity Registry
    WARNING: (shub://) to pull exactly equivalent images.
    /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
    ERROR: pulling container failed!


java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to pull singularity image
  command: singularity pull  --name quay.io-biocontainers-sickle-trim-1.33--2.img.pulling.1632265252300 docker://quay.io/biocontainers/sickle-trim:1.33--2 > /dev/null
  status : 127
  message:
    WARNING: pull for Docker Hub is not guaranteed to produce the
    WARNING: same image on repeated pull. Use Singularity Registry
    WARNING: (shub://) to pull exactly equivalent images.
    /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
    ERROR: pulling container failed!

    at nextflow.container.SingularityCache.getCachePathFor(SingularityCache.groovy:304)
    at nextflow.container.SingularityCache$getCachePathFor.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at nextflow.container.ContainerHandler.createSingularityCache(ContainerHandler.groovy:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at nextflow.container.ContainerHandler.normalizeImageName(ContainerHandler.groovy:68)
    at nextflow.container.ContainerHandler$normalizeImageName.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at nextflow.processor.TaskRun.getContainer(TaskRun.groovy:587)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:341)
    at nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor.createTaskHashKey(TaskProcessor.groovy:1939)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor.invokeTask(TaskProcessor.groovy:591)
    at nextflow.processor.InvokeTaskAdapter.call(InvokeTaskAdapter.groovy:59)
    at groovyx.gpars.dataflow.operator.DataflowOperatorActor.startTask(DataflowOperatorActor.java:120)
    at groovyx.gpars.dataflow.operator.ForkingDataflowOperatorActor.access$001(ForkingDataflowOperatorActor.java:35)
    at groovyx.gpars.dataflow.operator.ForkingDataflowOperatorActor$1.run(ForkingDataflowOperatorActor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to pull singularity image
  command: singularity pull  --name quay.io-biocontainers-sickle-trim-1.33--2.img.pulling.1632265252300 docker://quay.io/biocontainers/sickle-trim:1.33--2 > /dev/null
  status : 127
  message:
    WARNING: pull for Docker Hub is not guaranteed to produce the
    WARNING: same image on repeated pull. Use Singularity Registry
    WARNING: (shub://) to pull exactly equivalent images.
    /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
    ERROR: pulling container failed!

    at nextflow.container.SingularityCache.runCommand(SingularityCache.groovy:256)
    at nextflow.container.SingularityCache.downloadSingularityImage0(SingularityCache.groovy:223)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1029)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1012)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:101)
    at nextflow.container.SingularityCache$_downloadSingularityImage_closure1.doCall(SingularityCache.groovy:191)
    at nextflow.container.SingularityCache$_downloadSingularityImage_closure1.call(SingularityCache.groovy)
    at nextflow.file.FileMutex.lock(FileMutex.groovy:107)
    at nextflow.container.SingularityCache.downloadSingularityImage(SingularityCache.groovy:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1029)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1012)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:101)
    at nextflow.container.SingularityCache$_getLazyImagePath_closure2.doCall(SingularityCache.groovy:281)
    at nextflow.container.SingularityCache$_getLazyImagePath_closure2.call(SingularityCache.groovy)
    at groovyx.gpars.dataflow.LazyDataflowVariable$1.run(LazyDataflowVariable.java:70)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Sep-21 16:00:52.443 [Actor Thread 5] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session aborted -- Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to pull singularity image
  command: singularity pull  --name quay.io-biocontainers-sickle-trim-1.33--2.img.pulling.1632265252300 docker://quay.io/biocontainers/sickle-trim:1.33--2 > /dev/null
  status : 127
  message:
    WARNING: pull for Docker Hub is not guaranteed to produce the
    WARNING: same image on repeated pull. Use Singularity Registry
    WARNING: (shub://) to pull exactly equivalent images.
    /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
    ERROR: pulling container failed!

Sep-21 16:00:52.494 [Actor Thread 5] DEBUG nextflow.Session - The following nodes are still active:
[process] QC_TRIM_READS
  status=ACTIVE
  port 0: (queue) closed; channel: fastqFile
  port 1: (cntrl) -     ; channel: $

Sep-21 16:00:52.507 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await > all process finished
Sep-21 16:00:52.510 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await > all barriers passed
Sep-21 16:00:52.521 [main] DEBUG nextflow.trace.WorkflowStatsObserver - Workflow completed > WorkflowStats[succeededCount=0; failedCount=0; ignoredCount=0; cachedCount=0; pendingCount=0; submittedCount=0; runningCount=0; retriesCount=0; abortedCount=0; succeedDuration=0ms; failedDuration=0ms; cachedDuration=0ms;loadCpus=0; loadMemory=0; peakRunning=0; peakCpus=0; peakMemory=0; ]
Sep-21 16:00:52.685 [main] DEBUG nextflow.CacheDB - Closing CacheDB done
Sep-21 16:00:52.752 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Execution complete -- Goodbye
```

I have been using nf-core's rnaseq pipeline to guide me a bit: https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq

If it helps, here is the pipeline I am trying to automate: https://bioinformatics.uconn.edu/resources-and-events/tutorials-2/rna-seq-tutorial-with-reference-genome/#

My computer has a Windows 10 operating system, and I have enabled WSL2 and got Ubuntu.

I am fairly new to Docker, Singularity, and Nextflow so I am hoping someone can explain the error. I don't even understand why python is being mentioned. Is the issue that singularity cannot pull from Quay.io? I am a bit lost and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Also the reason I am trying to get singularity to work is STAR immediately gives me a Segmentation fault error on my local machine (i'm assuming I run out of memory), and I would like to test this pipeline on our HPC (but I don't have root privileges).

Comment: This looks like a problem pulling the image, not a Nextflow problem. Please see my answer below and I'll re-visit if it doesn't help.

Comment: BTW, you'll need about 30 GB of memory (or more) to index the human genome using STAR. Your local machine might not have this much. Mine doesn't.

Comment: Ya I came to the same conclusion, I run into quite a few issues trying to test this on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the Singularity warnings, but not the errors. The problem looks to be that you're missing `python` in your environment:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
ERROR: pulling container failed!
```

You need to make sure you have Python 3 installed. If you have, you should be able to see it here with:

```
/usr/bin/python --version
```

You didn't mention the version of Ubuntu you are using, but if you have Ubuntu 20.04 then you should already have Python 3 pre-installed. If this is the case, and you have Python 3 already installed (i.e. you find that `/usr/bin/python3 --version` works, note the '3') but the above doesn't, try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```

This will install a symlink to point the `/usr/bin/python` interpreter at the current default `python3`.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to have /usr/bin/python point towards the current conda env python version?

Comment: @MatthewKozubov no worries at all. Yes, but you really don't want to do that... do you still get `/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory` once you've activated your Python Conda environment? I.e. something like: `conda create --name py39 python=3.9; conda activate py39; singularity pull  --name quay.io-biocontainers-sickle-trim-1.33--2.img.pulling.1632264509884 docker://quay.io/biocontainers/sickle-trim:1.33--2`

Comment: I ran everything in my nf-core conda environment which should have python 3.8.11, is this version too small for singularity?

Comment: @MatthewKozubov Actually, I'm not sure why Singularity would complain about a missing Python. It's not a dependency. I'll have a dig through later and let you know what I find...

Comment: @MatthewKozubov I can't reproduce the error on my system using Singularity version 3.8.3. Thinking about this some more, I don't think it makes any sense what-so-ever trying to use both Singularity and Conda together since they are effectively trying to do similar things.

Comment: @MatthewKozubov I gave it a quick go just now (after creating and activating your Conda environment above) and running the workflow with `singularity.enabled = true`. And I have hit a permissions problem `ERROR: Could not create /dev/loop8: Permission denied`.

Comment: @MatthewKozubov regardless of the above, pulling the image using that environment is successful. Not sure exactly what is producing the error you're seeing...

Comment: thank you for trying, at this point I am just trying to stick to Docker.